# how to know if 2 projects are at the same appdomain

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, appdomain

I created 5 projects in the same solution assuming they all have the same app domain so they all can share static variables (as it's static per appdomain) so how do i make sure they are all on the same appdomain ? if they aren't how to make them all run at the same app domain.  also how could i give them the same namespace and they all still have their own namespaces ?

for instance `project1` namespace is `Bigproject.project1`, `project2` namespace is `Bigproject.project2` and so on ?

(i've had troubles trying to do that with a winf. app)

it's not one project with libraries, it's 2 console applications with 1 win form and 2 libraries, problem is one of the console form takes different instance from that library than the instance of the win form where by instance i refer to instance of static variable, thus i suspected that im not running on the same appdomain

Comment: Why do you need the projects to have the same namespace?

Comment: can you elaborate on your project types, are they class libraries, that are being use inside of one winform app, or are they all seperate winform applications?

Comment: "Requiring" that all libraries run in the same appdomain sounds like a brittle design.  Why is this a requirement other than the static variables?

Comment: question have been updated with all info requested

Comment: Look into WCF or some other flavor of inter-process communication since there are separate applications. Multiple processes cannot live in the same appdomain.

Answer (score 1):

AppDomains are specific to a process.  Just run them inside the same process.

A process can have multiple AppDomains. If you are creating AppDomains or running these assemblies in different processes, then you will manually have do manage the communication between them.

Comment: I would clarify your answer - AppDomains aren't specific to *Windows* processes, they're specific to *.Net* processes. AppDomains exist all the same in Mono on Linux.

Comment: Is there anyway I can access another app's appdomain.

Answer (score 1):

> I created 5 projects in the same solution assuming they all have the same app domain so they all can share static variables

If your solution has a single executable that references the other libraries I think that's a reasonable assumption.

> how do i make sure they are all on the same app domain ?

The app domain will be determined by the assembly that they're referenced from.  You can't "ensure" that two libraries will be loaded into the same app domain - it's entirely plausible for two separate applications to reference the libraries in separate app domains.

That said, if the libraries are referenced by the same *executable* then they *will* be in the same app domain (you have to explicitly load assemblies into a separate app domain)

> it's not one project with libraries, it's 2 console applications with 1 win form and 2 libraries

Then you need to use some sore of inter-process communication (web service, WCF), or a central repository (database).

Comment: no they actually have 3 executable, i've updated the question adding more about the problem

Comment: Then no, you'll need to use inter-process communication or some other strategy (service, database, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Projects are not synonymous with AppDomains, unless you are specifically creating a new app domain then all the objects you reference in your application are most likely in the same app domain via their entry point mechanism.  That mechanism could be an .exe or a web request under ASP.NET etc..

The common exceptions to this would be:

- When you are communicating via WCF or .NET Remoting (RPC, IPC)
- Communicating over any SOA transport like HTTP etc...

As for symptoms of communicating from one app domain to another you would see your call stacks having proxies in them, see `MarshalByRefObject` and `ContextBoundObject`